# listview can't see propaly in the fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment from the nav bar that has a listview that should include items to choose, but running the app I get "thinking screen"

here is FragmentClub.java

```
public class FragmentClubs extends ListFragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

ListView listView;
String[] names;
final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public FragmentClubs() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static FragmentClubs newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentClubs fragment = new FragmentClubs();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;}@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach () {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                              long id, boolean checked) {
            // Here you can do something when items are selected/de-selected,
            // such as update the title in the CAB
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.list:
                    mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu for the CAB
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.array.typesoffood, menu);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // Here you can make any necessary updates to the activity when
            // the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are deselected/unchecked.
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Here you can perform updates to the CAB due to
            // an invalidate() request
            return false;
        }


        public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

here is FragmentClubs.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.vlad.navig2.fragments.FragmentClubs"
android:weightSum="1"
android:clickable="true"
android:contextClickable="true"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/texttoeat"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:elegantTextHeight="false"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/submit"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="54dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="77dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Введіть..." />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />
```

Here is and image what i get while Running[That is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOCKM.png)
And me eatmenu.xml[eatmenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXwHQ.png)

Comment: You never add anything to the listview adapter. Why would you expect something to be displayed?

Comment: but is the screen I get is right?
Shouldn't I get just an empty fragment at that case?

Comment: You didn't implement `onCreateView`, so you are getting the default XML layout for a `ListFragment` which is a "thinking" icon and an empty list.

Comment: adding onCreateView method(absolutely empty) with just a return
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clubs, container, false);
the fragment crashes

Comment: Yeah, for the reason that you didn't [follow the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) for `ListFragment`. You view *must* contain a ListView with the id `@android:id/list`.

Comment: remove 'super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);' from 'onActivityCreated()' method and then add 'onCreateView()' method ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First -see Fragment Life cycle you called `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`' inside '`onActivityCreated()` that happens exactly after `onCreateView` and after `onCreate()` method ,this causes your app to fall in an endless loop ,
**and** you didnt inflate your layout in fragment that must be done in `onCreateView()` this causes your fragment show default empty list view not your desired one